# Prometheus Library Python - Dynamic instance name

Tags: python, prometheus

I'm using the Python Prometheus Library to instrument my application. Let's assume I have the following code:

```
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, Counter

data = {}
data['locations'] = 'berlin'

for i in data['location']
  metric = Counter("location_service_" + i + "_http_requests_count", "This metric tracks the requests from location: " + i)

metric.inc(1)
```

I'm struggling with the "metric" how can I make this dynamic based on the "location" value?

Comment: How about your current solution?

Comment: This is actually the current approach. However, I would like to have the "metric" dynamic. So: berlin.inc(1), munich.inc(1)

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use labels instead of changing the metric name. Using labels will make it easier to create dashboards/alerts. Here's how:

```py
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, Counter

label_names = ['location']
c = Counter("metric_name", "metric_descr", labelnames=label_names)
c.labels(location="berlin").inc()
```

Then you can query the value of this metric like this:

```
metric_name{location="berlin"}
```

More on querying [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/) and
I also encourage you to read [best practices](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/) on naming.

Comment: There's a reason why I don't want to use labels -->cardinality. I will have up to 6000 locations and I want to use the Prometheus changes function. I assume Prometheus won't be able to handle a metric with 6000 different label values.

Comment: @newduino Metric name is also a label (`__name__`), so it won't help you solve this problem.

Comment: So even 6000 different metrics will cause a problem? I though Prometheus can easily handle thousands of metrics.

Comment: @newduino Yes, Prometheus can handle millions of time series. The point is, there is no difference in one metric name with 6000 variations of a label and 6000 metrics with different names. It will be 6000 time series either way. The problem with cardinality of unbound labels comes from scaling. Imagine that you have one instance (hostA) that exposes 6000 time series. Then you set up another one (hostB) and there are 12,000 metrics now, because metrics from one instance has "hostA" label, and the metrics from another instance have "hostB" label.

Comment: Okey. Great. I didn't know that.